# How can I finish a ceiling around a propane gas line to fireplace?

Tags: gas

There is a propane line that goes to our gas fireplace. We want to finish our basement with drywall to the ceiling. What should we do with that line first?

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is the gas line in your picture? Is it that black thing in the ceiling, past the window? It looks weird, like there's a cover on it or something... ?

Comment: You've given us a great overview picture to show us the lay of the land, now a much closer picture to show what your actual concern is would be a _most_ helpful addition.

Comment: This question is entirely a matter of opinion. I certainly would not leave it there and cover it. I'd route it as it should've been originally--through the framing.

Comment: Generally, I'd agree with the VtC, however this is asking for how _can_ it be hidden, not how _should_ it be hidden. If you don't know the various methods for hiding things running across a ceiling this should be quite useful. If the OP asks for which method to choose, well, that's up to her.

Comment: I think the real question is: **Should a rubber gas hose, *Non metal pipe*,  be hidden and not accessible? and if so how to  future protect it from nails and screws?**

Comment: @AlaskaMan Rubber hose? Huh? Looks like perfectly appropriate CSST to me. Usually it's yellow but there's at least one brand that comes in black.

Answer (score 1):

In a case like this you can cove the corner or use crown molding.
Both methods leave the corner open and different sizes are available pre made.
The toughest part with crown molding is the compound bevel cut at the corners. As there is always some waste I cut in my corners and the match things with simpler cuts. Check it out makes a nice upscale look and hides pipe really well.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a coffered or tray ceiling, or simply put a soffit over the pipe.

- A soffit is a bump out on the wall/ceiling used to hide things like annoyingly installed plumbing.
- A tray ceiling has soffits on all 4 wall/ceiling intersections.
- A coffered ceiling is, essentially a grid of beams running across the surface of the ceiling.

They all offer decorative ways of hiding that one pipe, and potentially more.